# IPTABLES all networks getting dropped when i do the following

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

This is my first post, kindly help me out. I want to allow traffic from one network only and drop all, what am I doing wrong ? Output of my program is that its dropping packets on all. None of the sites are accessed once the script is run. DISTRO: Ubuntu 16.04

```
#Flush old
iptables -F 
iptables -X

#Allow loopback

iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#Allow DNS

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

#Accept IP, use your own IP

iptables -I INPUT -s $(IP) -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -s $(IP) -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#Drop rest

iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j REJECT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -j REJECT
```

Used reject and drop both, doesn't quite work.

Comment: The default `--policy` for the built-in (non-user-defined) chains is usually DROP. Your entire iptable looks rather bad designed. Whenever you use `-j ACCEPT` the "filtered" packet will immediately "jump" to the ACCEPT target and all other filters, which might try to filter this packet, will no longer be applied to that individual packet. Imagine iptables as a big ***Marble run*** for network packages.

Answer (score 0):

You are `I` inserting rather than `A` appending your `REJECT` rule to the table.

As the rules are read and applied in order, you are essentially inserting the reject rule to be read BEFORE the rest of the rules.

Try and change your `REJECT` rule to

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j REJECT
```

instead. Be sure to add

```
iptables-save
```

at the end of the script

Comment: I did check with A as well, same result. I am not saving because I only want this script for testing once on target